# Unable to map API data to react native Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to render a map API data to picker, but I'm getting an error that
it's not rendering anything inside picker. Picker is blank, can someone help me?

That is my action to get api

```
const LIST_INDUSTRIES = getApiUrl('/Client/list_industries');

export const listIndustried = (query = '') => {
  return apiGet(LIST_INDUSTRIES + query);
};
```

that my main api code with picker component

```
state={
Industries: [],
selectedIndustry: "",
}

  componentDidMount() {
    actions
      .listIndustried()
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          Industry: res.data,
        });
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

<Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedIndustries}
              mode="dropdown"
              dropdownIconColor="#eb8034"
              onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({selectedIndustries: value})}>
              {this.state.Industry.map((item, key) => (
                <Picker.Item
                  label={item.name}
                  value={item.name}
                  key={key}
                />
              ))}
            </Picker>
```

Comment: what is result of `console.log(res)` above `let list_Industries = res;`?

Comment: ` [{"_id": "5fc64edcc38e9da0bafefad3", "name": "Test"}, {"_id": "5fc64f91c38e9da0bafefad4", "name": "Test1"}]`

Comment: @AlanOmar that's the result of console.log(res)

Comment: then use `this.state.Industry.map` instead of `this.state.list_Industries.map`

Comment: I updated my question please check

Comment: do you have `list_Industries` property in your state?

Comment: nop check my componentdidMount

Comment: then use `{this.state.Industry.map((item, key) =>` instead of `{this.state.list_Industries.map((item, key) =>`

Comment: done but still picker is blank

Comment: @AlanOmar it's worked thanks

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome